# python os.rename(...) won't work !

Tags: python, file-rename

I am writing a Python function to change the extension of a list of files into another extension, like txt into rar, that's just an idle example. But I'm  getting an error. The code is:

```
import os
def dTask():
    #Get a file name list
    file_list = os.listdir('C:\Users\B\Desktop\sil\sil2')
    #Change the extensions
    for file_name in file_list:
        entry_pos = 0;
        #Filter the file name first for '.'
        for position in range(0, len(file_name)):
            if file_name[position] == '.':
                break
        new_file_name = file_name[0:position]
        #Filtering done !
        #Using the name filtered, add extension to that name
        new_file_name = new_file_name + '.rar'
        #rename the entry in the file list, using new file name
        print 'Expected change from: ', file_list[entry_pos]
        print 'into File name: ', new_file_name
        os.rename(file_list[entry_pos], new_file_name)
        ++entry_pos
Error:
>>> dTask()
Expected change from:  New Text Document (2).txt
into File name:  New Text Document (2).rar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    dTask()
  File "C:\Users\B\Desktop\dTask.py", line 19, in dTask
    os.rename(file_list[entry_pos], new_file_name)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I can succeed in getting the file name with another extension in variable level as you can see in the print-out, but not in reality because I can not end this process in OS level. The error is coming from os.rename(...). Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: __++entry_pos__ don't do what you think it do. i think you want to do __entry_pos += 1__

Answer (score 9):

1. As the others have already stated, you either need to provide the path to those files or switch the current working directory so the os can find the files.
2. `++entry_pos` doesn't do anything. There is no increment operator in Python. Prefix `+` is just there fore symmetry with prefix `-`. Prefixing something with two `+` is just two no-ops. So you're not actually doing anything (and after you change it to `entry_pos += 1`, you're still resetting it to zero in each iteration.
3. Also, your code is very inelegant - for example, you are using a separate index to `file_list` and fail to keep that in synch with the iteration variable `file_name`, even though you could just use that one! To show how this can be done better.

-

```
def rename_by_ext(to_ext, path):
    if to_ext[0] != '.':
        to_ext = '.'+to_ext
    print "Renaming files in", path
    for file_name in os.listdir(path):
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
        print "Renaming", file_name, "to", root+ext
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join(path, root+to_ext))
rename_by_ext('.rar', '...')
```

Comment: Thanks for the warnings. I tend to write C++, putting brackets after ifs, strings into "", and ++, --, stuff, which I will adapt in time not to. Very fresh beginner for python, thus incompetent. Two things: In your code, ... + from_ext. I didn't understand that. It has garbage value. It looks dangling, never used after that point. 2) In comment 3: you are using a separate index to file_list and fail to keep that in synch with the iteration variable file_name : To broaden my horizon, could you explain in details what you mean ? Thank you.

Comment: @Mr ME: (1) `from_ext` was left over from copypasta, thanks for catching it. (2) The sole purpose of `entry_pos`, as far as I can see, is to get the name of the current file in `print 'Expected change from: ', file_list[entry_pos]`, although you could (and should) simply use `file_name`.

Answer (score 3):

os.rename really doesn't like variables. Use shutil. Example taken from [How to copy and move files with Shutil](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/python-the-shutil-module).

```
import shutil
import os
source = os.listdir("/tmp/")
destination = "/tmp/newfolder/"
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.move(files,destination)
```

In your case:

```
import shutil
shutil.move(file_list[entry_pos], new_file_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You also want to double backslashes to escape them in Python strings, so instead of

```
file_list = os.listdir('C:\Users\B\Desktop\sil\sil2')
```

you want

```
file_list = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\B\\Desktop\\sil\\sil2')
```

Or use forward slashes - Python magically treats them as path separators on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the useful info. I was never aware of that and totally missed it.

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't make a difference; only certain characters following a backslash are specially treated (\b is a backspace, but \B is \B). It will eventually bite you in the ass if you aren't aware of it though.

Comment: I have corrected my code and it is fully working. But that's only inside IDLE. When I click the .py file, it doesn't function as a .bat or .exe. I realized that it is not directly executable. Do I have to use IDLE all the time to call the script ? I mean, there must be a way to work the script directly. Would you have anything to say about that ? Thank you.

Comment: You have a command line python.exe somewhere and should be able to set up file type handling in windows to run 'python.exe scriptname.py' when you launch a python file.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the full path for the rename.

```
import os
def dTask():
    #Get a file name list
    dir = 'C:\Users\B\Desktop\sil\sil2'
    file_list = os.listdir(dir)
    #Change the extensions
    for file_name in file_list:
        entry_pos = 0;
        #Filter the file name first for '.'
        for position in range(0, len(file_name)):
            if file_name[position] == '.':
                break
        new_file_name = file_name[0:position]
        #Filtering done !
        #Using the name filtered, add extension to that name
        new_file_name = new_file_name + '.rar'
        #rename the entry in the file list, using new file name
        print 'Expected change from: ', file_list[entry_pos]
        print 'into File name: ', new_file_name
        os.rename( os.path.join(dir, file_list[entry_pos]), os.path.join(dir,new_file_name))
        ++entry_pos
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't in the directory `C:\Users\B\Desktop\sil\sil2`, then Python certainly won't be able to find those files.

Answer (score -4):

```
import os

def extChange(path,newExt,oldExt=""):
    if path.endswith != "\\" and path.endswith != "/":
        myPath = path + "\\"
    directory = os.listdir(myPath)
    for i in directory:
        x = myPath + i[:-4] + "." + newExt
        y = myPath + i
        if oldExt == "":
            os.rename(y,x)
        else:
            if i[-4:] == "." + oldExt:
                os.rename(y,x)
```

now call it:

```
extChange("C:/testfolder/","txt","lua") #this will change all .txt files in C:/testfolder to .lua files
extChange("C:/testfolder/","txt") #leaving the last parameter out will change all files in C:/testfolder to .txt
```

Comment: -1 Your code is horrible (using `i` `x` and `y`) and won't work: `path.endswith != "\\"` is always `False`