# Having Problems with Arguments

Tags: python

I have tried to write this little script that will batch rename file extensions. I am passing three arguments, the directory where the files are located, the current extension, and the new extension.

The error I am getting is

```
python batch_file_rename_2.py c:\craig .txt .html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "batch_file_rename_2.py", line 13, in <module>
  os.rename(filename, newfile) 
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The code is

```
import os
import sys

work_dir=sys.argv[1]
old_ext=sys.argv[2]
new_ext=sys.argv[3]

files = os.listdir(work_dir)
for filename in files:
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if old_ext == file_ext:
        newfile = filename.replace(old_ext, new_ext)
        os.rename(filename, newfile)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOError when trying to open existing files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802418/ioerror-when-trying-to-open-existing-files)

Comment: also see [python os.rename(...) won't work !](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4147438)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns only the filenames, not complete paths. Use `os.path.join` to recreate the correct path:

```
for filename in files:
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if old_ext == file_ext:
        newfile = filename.replace(old_ext, new_ext)
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(work_dir, filename), 
            os.path.join(work_dir, newfile))
```

Comment: you've forgotten the second os.path.join

Comment: Thanks very much that has sorted the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must specify fullname when you are not in the directory (you are not):

```
os.rename(os.path.join(work_dir, filename), os.path.join(work_dir, newfile))
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `os.listdir` returns only filenames without path, you should use function `os.path.join` to join `work_dir` and `filename`.

And line `newfile = filename.replace(old_ext, new_ext)` looks very unsafe because it can replace not only extension but some unexpected parts of filename.

You can replace file extension in more safe way using `os.path` functions, `splitext` for example.